# Alternatives for (not working) nested substitution arguments for roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, xml, launch-file

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´m currently changing the launch file setup on a project and would like to do something like

```
<include file="$(find $(env ROBOT_TYPE)_config)/launch/planning_config.launch">
```

This doesn´t appear to be possible. There is a workaround by creating one launch file per robot type and referencing that, but I was wondering if there are other options that I missed and that do not require creating one launch file per robot type. I´m hoping I´m missing some otherwise obvious simple alternative here ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81676/alternatives-for-(not-working)-nested-substitution-arguments-for-roslaunch/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had the same issue and never found a real solution. One thing that may be a work around is to use xacro ( http://wiki.ros.org/xacro ) to generate the launch files for each robot.  You can run xacro from makefiles (at least in rosbuild you could ).

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See my answer to a similar question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/35283/nested-substitution-args-in-launch-files/?answer=236054#post-id-236054

This is now made possible by a feature added to roslaunch version 1.12.1, released April 18, 2016. (ATM the debian repos are at version 1.12.0, so you'll either have to wait or download the github sources)

roslaunch 1.12.1 adds support for evaluation of arbitrary python expressions using the syntax `$(eval <expression>)`. With this change, the following is possible:

```
<include file="$(eval find(env('ROBOT_TYPE') + '_config') + '/launch/planning_config.launch')">
```

---

Originally posted by [juztamau5](https://answers.ros.org/users/27070/juztamau5/) with karma: 86 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1